# How do I keep some of the content of a mounted div, in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm converting our app from Vue v2, to v3. The legacy code mounts to a div with id=app, but it doesn't replace the entire div. Instead it swaps the divs within 'app', which have the same id as its components with those same components. I am trying to copy this behaviour, without success. Does Vue 3 not have this behaviour or what should I do to achieve this?

```
<div id="app">
   <div id="vue-someDiv"></div>
</div>
```

if I have a component called 'someDiv' as a component of my mounted (to 'app') application, I would expect that contents to appear. But in v3, it doesn't appear to.

Comment: Could it be that your previous app was using server side rendering (SSR)? It seems related to client-side hydration, check the documentation here maybe: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html

Comment: Good that you alerted me to this possibility. Thanks.

Comment: Different mount behavior in v2 vs v3 is described [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/mount-changes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just mount the app into another div like `<div id="app-entry">` and append it's content to `<div id="#app">` with:

```
[...document.querySelector('#app-entry').children].forEach(chlid => document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(child));
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but v-slot is the behaviour I am after

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be simpler to use the app component to place sub-components. I have not used vue-2, but using components in vue-3 is about placing them within the app component.

```
<template> 
         <!-- html content here --!>
         <SomeDiv />   
</template>
```

Within the app.vue, you have the template where you can place the html foundation along with the content of your components. Instead of using `id="vue-someDiv"` to use the component, you can just use the component using `<SomeDiv />`

Comment: I notice though, that there are many css styles in these divs that seem to be maintained by the replacing divs.

Comment: Does the id vue-someDiv have a css style definition? If not then the styles of the component should be determined from the inside of the sub-components no?

Comment: I am still trying to understand this code, but yes it seems the styles hardcoded inside vue-someDiv are maintained in the final view.

Answer (score 0):

[v-slot](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) is the bevaviour I'm after.